# How can I create a moped DC source from the alternator using the chassis as common GND for both AC and DC?

Tags: generator, bridge-rectifier

I need to convert from AC to DC the output of the red wire coming from the right stator coil (marked with R) which is the one that feeds the lamps.

The idea is to convert to DC then regulate the output to be able to use LEDs.

[image: Honda PC50 wiring]

*Figure 1. Honda PC50 wiring diagram.*

Comment: A rectifier then a 12V dc to 3 V dc converter. 3V is just a guess - make sure it is suitable for the LEDS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ground **both** the AC and DC, then the easiest option is a voltage doubler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJCdj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One half cycle delivers power to the output. The other half cycle recharges the flying capacitor. Use suitably beefy diodes, not the default 1N4148s shown there. Use large enough capacitors for your frequency and current requirements.

Don't want double the voltage? Tough, use a buck converter to drop it to what you actually need.